# How to configure a reverse Proxy between two IIS 7 Servers

Tags: iis-7

I have Server A with a IIS 7 which is available for all incoming requests. The backend server is in a vpn so the access is restricted. Now I need to allow access to one application of the backend-server for all incoming request and not only from the vpn. Is it possible to solve this with this infrastructure? Can I configure my SERVER A (this has access to the backend server) so that it acts as a proxy to my backend-server? At my backend server I am using isapi.dll for the redirection to my tomcat servers.

Can someone explain how to solve this?